# My autolayout is not working for all screens

Tags: ios, xcode, autolayout, xib

[This is my layout](https://i.stack.imgur.com/11osm.png) when run on IPhone5.
I am using AutoLayout to design app. It works well.
But, when I run it on IPhone6 Plus, it does not [look great](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dx5VL.png).
I don't know what happens.

Please help me.

Comment: check some auto layout tutorials. i guess you have given fixed constraints to all elements in screen. if you post the only controller with sample project in Xcode 7.3, i can do changes for constraints. but my concern is, you should understand how you need to use those.

Comment: Have you set the top, bottom, trailing and leading constraint for table view? Please show the constraints you have added so far.

Comment: Yes, I know. only this app meet this problem. Some others app is working nomal.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set tableview as per below screenshot.

[image]

Comment: all screens like that.

Comment: only this app meet this problem. Some others app is working nomal.

Comment: then you need to mention more explanation about this issue.

Comment: View have four position.x,y,height and width.we can achieve by autolayout. this x,y position,height and width are constraints.

Comment: @VõMaiTrinh Add constraints only Leading,Trailing,Top and height it will fit for all devices, don't set the fixed width.

Comment: Yes, I know. And, I founda reason, I am using BATabBarController. When I add My ViewController to this tabbar, my constrains is not working.

Answer (score 0):

I think setting Autoresize Subviews for your ViewController might help.

1. Click your ViewController in storyboard
2. Click View
3. Click the
   Autoresize Subviews option

[image: Check the Autoresize Subviews property]